# Is it possible to constrain a mapped type to ONLY its keys but let them be optional

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a function that excepts a state object and then another object with reducer like functions.  I want the function to only accept the second argument if the keys of the object belong to the state object.  But I don't want it to demand that all keys are present, only an optional set of them.  Furthermore I want one extra key to be allowed on the incoming reducer argument that is not a key of the state object.

So something like this:

```js
type TWithExtraKey <T> = T & {extraKey: any};  

function build<TState, TReducers extends {[TKeys in keyof TWithExtraKey<TState>] : {
    [TChildKeys in keyof TReducers[TKeys]]: (a, b) => TState
}}>(initialState: TState, reducers: TReducers){
  // do stuff
};
```

My problem is I want to constrain TReducers to be an object only with keys from TState, but not necessarily all of them and to also allow the extra key.

So with this state and reducer object in mind:

```js
const someState = {
    propOne: {
        e: 44
    },
    propTwo: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
    },
    propThree: {
        c: false,
        d: "string",
    },
};

const someReducers = {
    extraKey: {
        someReducerExtra: (a, b) => a
    },
    propTwo: {
        someReducerA: (a, b) => a,
        someReducerB: (a, b) => a,
    },

    propThree: {
        someReducerC: (a, b) => a,
        someReducerD: (a, b) => a,
    },
};
```

if I try to send it in:

```
build(someState, someReducers);  // Error: 'propOne' is declared here.
```

I  can change the keyof TReducers to be optional :

```js
function build<TState, TReducers extends {[TKeys in keyof TWithExtraKey<TState>]? : {
    [TChildKeys in keyof TReducers[TKeys]]: (a, b) => TState
}}>(initialState: TState, reducers: TReducers){
  // do stuff
};
```

But then I can send in anything in someReducers and I don't want that.

```js
const someReducers = {
    propTwo: {
        someReducerA: (a, b) => a,
        someReducerB: (a, b) => a
    },

    asdfas: {
        someReducerC: (a, b) => a,
        someReducerD: (a, b) => a
    }
}

build(someState, someReducers);  // Works... But I want it to yell at me for using asdfas as its not a key of TWithExtraKey<TState>.
```

So is there a way to constrain TReducers keys to only be those of TWithExtraKey? And yet still allow an arbitrary optional set of them?

I will be sending in varying states so the structure of the state will vary.

Comment: [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOLglN) is something that could solve your problem

Comment: @Filly thank you! This indeed helped my solve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Filly I was able to solve the issue.

It now looks like this:

```js
// A created type for the validation of the reducer object:
type XValidateReducers<
    TState,
    TReducers extends {
        [TKeys in keyof TWithExtraKey<TState>]?: {
            [TChildKeys in keyof TReducers[TKeys]]: (a, b) => TState;
        };
    },
    ExtraKey extends string
> = {
    [K in keyof TReducers]: K extends keyof TState ? TReducers[K] : K extends ExtraKey ? TReducers[K] : never;
};

//I can then create a method with the following signature:

export function build<
    TState,
    TReducers extends {
        [TKeys in keyof TWithExtraKey<TState>]?: {
            [TChildKeys in keyof TReducers[TKeys]]: (a, b) => TState;
        };
    } & TKeySelection,
    TKeySelection extends XValidateReducers<TState, TReducers, "extraKey">
>(initialState: TState, reducers: TReducers) {}
```

The method will now allow the reducers to have one or more properties that match the keys of state and the extra key, but disallow objects that have keys that are not included in state or the extra key.

So

```js
const state = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4};

validReducer1 = {one: (a,b) => a}
validReducer2 = {two: (a,b) => a, four: : (a,b) => a, extraKey: (a,b) => a}
validReducer3 = {extraKey: (a,b) => a}
validReducer4 = {two: (a,b) => a, three: (a,b) => a}

invalidReducer = {five: (a,b) => a}
invalidReducer = {six: (a,b) => a, extraKey: (a,b) => a}
```